# google apps script to send spreadsheet pdf

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new at this and I think I'm trying to do something a little complicated.  Ultimately I'm looking to do the following:  I would like to have a spreadsheet that upon a submit button does the following, sends spreadsheet to a specified email address, then increases a specified cell number by 1, then clears data that was entered in specific cells.
I have figured out how to increase a cell on a button push that's as far as I have gotten.  Any chance someone would be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would say you should catch `change` event at master and prevent bubbling to child control

Answer (score 0):

For your emailing you want to use [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)

The PDF conversion mentioned in the subject line is also pretty easy to use [Spreadsheet.getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getBlob())  or if you want to be a bit more verbose [Spreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf')](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getAs(String))

Generally the [GoogleAPI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) is pretty good at explaining a lot of the detail on how to connect to the google libraries